# Include a date in a txt file

Tags: python

I want to include the date on to this file so it would be unity20130723.txt How do I go about it. I have this so far:

```
dt =datetime.datetime.now()
f=open('unity.txt', 'w')
for issue in data["issues"]:
   f.write(issue ['key'])
   f.write(issue['fields']['summary']) 
   f.write('\n')


f.close()
```

I love the Answers here I also made an addition to the script to give me 2 digits for the months and days. It will look like this in case any one is looking for how to.

```
f=open('unity{}{}{}.txt'.format(dt.year, '%02d' % dt.month, '%02d' % dt.day), 'w')
```

Comment: Use `with` when working with files.

Comment: To continue mishik's comment, `with` will ensure the file is closed properly in the case of an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the different fields of `dt` using `dt.year`, `dt.month`, `dt.day`. So if you wanted to put the date in the name of the file you could do

```
f=open('unity{}{}{}.txt'.format(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day), 'w')
```

EDIT: [Brien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17811993/2452770) is really elegant, I would use that in conjunction with the `format` code I used here.

Answer (score 3):

An easy way is using [`time.strftime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime).

```
>>> import time

>>> time.strftime('%Y%m%d')
'20130723'

>>> time.strftime('unity%Y%m%d.txt')
'unity20130723.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
f_timestamp = "".join([dt.year, dt.month, dt.day])
filename = "unity{}.txt".format(f_timestamp)
with open(filename, "w") as f:
    for issue in data["issues"]:
        f.write(issue ['key'])
        f.write(issue['fields']['summary']) 
        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_name = 'Unity_%s.txt' % dt.strftime(format='%Y%m%d')
```

[Strftime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime) is all you need and will output something like `Unity_20130723.txt`

Then just do:

```
f=open(file_name, 'w')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

FORMAT = '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'
path = 'unity.txt'
data = 'your data'
new_path = '%s%s' % (path, datetime.now().strftime(FORMAT))
open(new_path, 'w').write(data)
```